# Proving grammar equivalence in simple grammar (generate any sequence of three characters)

Tags: formal-grammars

Goal is proving grammar equivalence

---

Upper-case symbols are non-terminal.

Lower-case symbols are terminal.

The start symbol is `S`.

A grammar production rule is **non-terminals-only** if it only contains non-terminals. For example: `AB -> CDE`

A grammar rule is **non-terminal-to-terminal** if the left side has one non-terminal and the right side has one terminal. For example: `A -> a` `B -> b`

A grammar is **aterminal** if:

- The number of terminals equals the number of non-terminals
- All rules are non-terminals-only or non-terminal-to-terminal
- Each non-terminal has a corresponding terminal via a non-terminal-to-terminal rule (and each terminal appears exactly once in a non-terminal-to-terminal rule)

For example:

Grammar 1

```
S -> SS
S -> A

S -> s
A -> a
```

It's called aterminal, because, in some sense, there's no distinction between terminals and non-terminals.

All grammars in this question are unrestricted, but aterminal.

---

If you start with a sequence of symbols, and use multiple production rules to generate a new sequence of symbols, you can consider that an additional (but redundant) rule.

For example:

Grammar 2:

```
A -> BB
B -> CC
C -> AA

A -> a
B -> b
C -> c
```

If we start with a non-terminal `B`:

```
B (we happen to start with B)
CC (B -> CC)
AAC (C -> AA)
AAAA (C -> AA)
```

Therefore we can add `B -> AAAA` to the grammar without changing the language it recognizes.

---

Grammar 3

```
S -> SS
S -> A
S -> B

S -> s
A -> a
B -> b
```

Grammar 3 generates any (non-empty) sequence of `s`,`a` and `b`. For example, to generate `sab`:

```
S (start rule)
SS (S -> SS)
SSS (S -> SS)
SAS (S -> A)
SAB (S -> B)
sAB (S -> s)
saB (A -> a)
sab (B -> b)
```

---

Grammar 4

```
S -> SS
S -> A
AA -> B

S -> s
A -> a
B -> b
```

Using the idea from Grammar 2, we can start with `S` and derive:

```
S (happen to start with S)
SS (S -> SS)
AS (S -> A)
AA (S -> A)
B (AA -> B)
```

Therefore we can derive `S -> B` as an additional rule.

**I believe now, having add `S -> B`, we can remove `AA -> B` and thus Grammars 3 and 4 are equivalent, but I don't know how to prove this. Is this right??? If so, what's the proof???**

Here's my progress:

Additionally, we can derive `S -> AA`.

Now we have three rules of this form:

```
X -> Y
Y -> Z
X -> Z
```

Namely:

```
S -> AA
AA -> B
S -> B
```

Maybe when you have 3 rules of this form, AND the only way to get `Y` is by "first going through `X`", then you can remove the `Y -> Z` rule. I don't know if this is right or how to formalize this.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove grammar equivalence by showing that they represent the same language,use fixed pont iteration method to find language of context free grammar.